# react, spfx and taxonomy

Tags: spfx, taxonomy, react

I am using react to get the term by id, but the problems is that I am not able to get any child term under the term.For example:

-IT

--software

--hardware

IT is term not termSet.

taxonomy.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore()
        .getTermById(this.props.top)
        .get().then(
            Alltop=>{
                console.log(Alltop)
                this.setState({terms:Alltop})
            }
        );

for termSet I am able to get all terms using
taxonomy.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore()
        .getTermSetById(this.props.terSetId).terms
        .get()

Answer (score 2):

Use PNP SP taxonomy in your SPFX code as below,it easy to use and supported with SPFx

```
import {
    taxonomy,
    ITermStore,
    ITerms,
    ILabelMatchInfo,
    ITerm,
    ITermData
} from "@pnp/sp-taxonomy";

const store: ITermStore = await taxonomy.termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_v5o/SbcTE2cegwO2dtAN9l==");

// get a single term by id
const term: ITerm = store.getTermById("0ba6845c-1468-4ec5-a5a8-718f1fb05431");

// get single get merged with data
const term2: ITerm = store.getTermById("0ba6845c-1468-4ec5-a5a8-718f1fb05431").get();

// use select to choose which fields to return
const term3: ITerm = store.getTermById("0ba6845c-1468-4ec5-a5a8-718f1fb05431").select("Name").get();

// get a term from a term set
const term4: ITerm = store.getTermSetById("0ba6845c-1468-4ec5-a5a8-718f1fb05431").getTermById("0ba6845c-1468-4ec5-a5a8-718f1fb05431");
```

Ref - https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp-taxonomy/docs/terms/